# "In-App Hosted Content" meaning - iOS 6 Release

Tags: ios6

Does this mean that now I am able to store information (video, image, text, etc) in a (kind of) web service provided by apple?

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA. Your question is more appropriate on Apple dev forums.

Comment: so I can feed my apps storing information in apple servers?